# Reusable Activity

Tags: android

Scenario is like this,
I have a Media player which plays the music onClick of song in playlist.
It is working fine in my case.
But the problem is that, I want a button on each screen which directly take to Media Player.
If I use startActivity(intent); on onClick of the button it creates new music player Activity.
I dnt want that, I want to reuse my previous media player Activit

Comment: Please mark a answer. Its not nice to leave just like that.

Answer (score 1):

I am imagining that you have the activity on the bottom of the current Activity stack , and you want to bring that activity to the top. You need to set some flags on the intent with `Intent.addFlags()`. Check the documentation  for [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) and the flags [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) and [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT). Also consider singleTop and singleInstance activities

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Background service to take of your now playing song and start the activity and get the current playing progress from service and set in the activity.

Also set the flag for history to launch and start the activity from history also.

Comment: yes I am using service for playing the song in background.
But when the media player is in background onClick of button i want display same running media player without disturbing it.